# Capture a GUID that is part of key name from registry and turn it into variable

Tags: windows-registry, guid

Im trying to capture a specific `GUID` from registry that is unique (naturally) and changing from time to time. Then turn it into variable that i can use in `REG ADD` operation (i know that part).

The key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video`

The `Video` subkey itself contains 8-10 GUID-s as subkey names. Whats unique about the name of the subkey i want to capture is that it contains more subfolders like 0002, 0003 and so on (other subkeys only contain up to 0001).

In fact i was able to capture this GUID by searching for subkeys with 0005 in it. Naturally this was the only match. I used the following command: `REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video /s /f 0005 /k` wich is giving me:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{E7DC82FD-9088-411B-9B0A-2FED7F034E03}\0005
End of search: 1 match(es) found.
```

Now if i could only extract the `{E7DC82FD-9088-411B-9B0A-2FED7F034E03}` part and turn it into variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command will get the required GUID and sets the GUID environment variable to this value:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=6 delims=\" %a in (`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video /s /f 0005 /k`) do set GUID=%a
```